# Please blacklist the TV tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

A recently-created tag, [tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) should be blacklisted. It's a given that everything on the site will be about a movie or TV show, so having such a uselessly broad tag is not helpful. Usually, tags that match a SE's site name are auto-blacklisted for this reason, it looks like this one slipped through the cracks.

Comment: Mmm, I agree with the sentiment - but having looked at the tag management pages, don't know how to do this via the tools. Is this something that can only be done by making a request to the SE staff?

Comment: SE staff have the tools.

Comment: In this case `movie` (which I have already seen, and removed, somewhere) should be, too.

Comment: Given that this tag [has been used recently](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18797/49), I wonder what "blacklisting" actually does at all.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I tried to do a sample question, it disallowed the movie tag, but seems to allow the tv tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added `tv` and `movie` to the tags blacklist.

Comment: You sure? See Napoleon's comment above.

Comment: Yes, it would appear that the tv is not / no longer blacklisted for some reason.

Comment: TV as a tag seems more and more like it *could* have relevance as opposed to making a fargo-tv tag and a from-dusk-to-dawn-tv tag, etc. As more movie becomes series why make a new tag for each when there's an easier, more efficient way?

Comment: Could someone please finally explain what's the actual deal with blacklisting and what the final decision for those tags is? Since yet again this answer seems [wrong](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9301/49).

Comment: For the same reason, shouldn't the [tag:television] tag be blacklisted too?

Comment: Why is this not blacklisted??? We just had it created... again... http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46891/the-sopranos-list-of-actors-looked-at-for-tonys-role

Comment: @Catija - don't know. I've re-added it.